# Flash to SignalR communication

Tags: flash, actionscript, signalr

We have a service communicating back and forth in realtime over SignalR. We have a HTML5 frontend, but I would like to try to make a Flash/Actionscript frontend with AIR that I can compile to a native iOS/Android app. Is there a library available to communicate with the SignalR server hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Flash/ActionScript proxy generator at this time. It's fairly trivial to create given that ActionScript is basically just JavaScript anyway. All you would need to do is create a custom [`IJavaScriptProxyGenerator`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/SignalR/Hubs/IJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs) implementation which emits a proxy that best leverages and exposes itself to the ActionScript runtime.

You can clone the [`DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/SignalR/Hubs/DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs) as a jumping off point (call it `ActionScriptProxyGenerator`) and then just replace the portions of the implementation that emit jQuery based patterns/impl to emit ActionScript based patterns/impl instead.

Then all you would do is hit the Hub endpoint to download the script into Flash (or you can save it and build right into the Flash component statically) and then you're off and running.

If you end up doing this I'm sure the SignalR project and other Flash devs would love if you contributed it back, so please be sure to send a pull request if you do!

Comment: ActionScript is NOT "just" JavaScript.  JavaScript is not strongly-typed but ActionScript is.

Comment: Thanks, I know exactly what ActionScript is and what makes it different from JavaScript. For the record, it doesn't have to be strongly typed (i.e. var[:*]) which then makes it EXACTLY like JavaScript. Anyway, one of the things you would obviously change in the proxy generator implementation is to add strong types to the parameters/return values as you generate the proxy. Since you have full access to the .NET signature you can map the intrinsic types very easily as well as emit strong ActionScript types for any custom classes being used in the signature if you wanted to.

Comment: I'm afraid that would go to far. Was hoping for some "out of the box" code:-) Thanks for the explantion!

Comment: ActionScript is NOT exactly like JavaScript.  JavaScript, for example, has two different operators "typeof" and "instanceof" which work differently and utterly inconsistantly.  One will only identify primitive types, and the other won't identify *some* primitive types and throws and error on null and undefined values.  It's an epic fail.  See: http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/

On the other hand, ActionScript has strong-types and can use the "is" keyword exclusively to correctly identify types without ever throwing an error.  AS3 left AS2 and JavaScript in the dust.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still interested, I have a full working demo of signalR to as3 via  javascript bridge here:

https://github.com/blinemedical/SignalRToAs3

The repo readme has an explanation of what is going on as well as a compilable backend in .net and a frontend in as3/flex to demonstrate whats going on.  The sample uses an old version of fluorine for object serialization but any version should work.   If you have questions feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few options for you:

1. Use [FluorineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/), open sourced project, and look into the usage of Publisher/Consumer for your real-time communicate.  FluorineFX would convert your .Net object strongly-typed into ActionScript objects which saves you tons of time of serialization and deserialization.  You can also use FluorineFX to make RPC calls as well for non-real-time communication.
2. Use [WebOrb.NET](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html) if you prefer supported commercial product.  WebOrb is well-rounded and has been around for a long time.  It has all the advantage FluorineFX has except it is a closed-source product.
3. Flash has been supporting real-time, stateful communication via XMLSocket since 2001, which is similar to WebSocket.  You can have SignalR publish the objects, in XML format, to the XMLSocket.  You would have to write your own XML serializer and de-serializer with this option, plus the performance would be worse as XML parsing is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested in this, I have a SignalR Flex/AS3 client swc available at https://github.com/jmichas/SignalRF. It operates much the same as the .Net client. Usage examples are available on the github site.